# how to fix a value inside a buttons onclicklistner using loop which is used to call the same method everytime

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is my code,I am calling the same method from each button with different value. What I want is a loop from which I can set the "value" to every button.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                operation(int value);
            }
        });

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                operation(int value);
            }
        });

button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                operation(int value);
            }
        });

public void operation(int value){
  if(value==1)
     //some operation
  else if(value==2)
    //some operation
  else
    //some operation
}
```

Comment: Please be specific what u want to do ?

Comment: Could you try using a `switch-case` on the `View` in the `onClick` parameter and setting the `onClickListener` to the parent of these buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:onClick="buttonOnClick"` attribute in each Buttons you have, Then use `buttonOnClick` method like this,

```
public void buttonOnClick(View view)
{
    operation(int value);
}
```

And if you have some additional things to do with specific buttons you can switch `view.getId()` for each buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I know that, I have three buttons in which I am calling the same method, I want to set an "int value" using a loop. so, when we click that button it has a different value which gives a different result.